# accessibility in Edge Animate Down-level Stage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8, adobe-edge

I am really new to JS and have a project in Adobe Edge Animate that is being served to many running n IE8 browser with a special 508/WCAG2.0 requirement.  This means alt tags and tabindex functions are a MUST for their visually impaired staff (using web page readers like JAWS).

How can I add this functionality to the Down-Level stage?  I have opened the edge_preload.js file and have added multiple combinations of:

alt: '....',
title: '....',
tabindex: '....',
tag: `"<a href="" alt=""><img src="" /></a>",`

I've also tried encapsulating in square brackets, i.e. [ syntax ] and nothing results in alt tags popping up when viewing the Down-level page.  It almost seems like alt and title tags are completely ignored by IE8.

Please help and thank you so much for your time.

***edit - 1/13/2015***
In doing more research I downloaded a copy of  JAWS V15.0 (40 minute trial) and found that it doesn't read the Down-Level stage AT ALL.  Tabbing jumps right over all of the content from one of the top IE toolbars to the bottom of the IE window status bar.

Somebody out there, please help with some hint or something new to try...

Answer (score 0):

Do you have tried it with another screen reader like NVDA? In many cases NVDA give better results in webviews, and it's free and better equivalent to JAWS.
(http://www.nvaccess.org/)